# Problema pra publicar projeto - GitHub

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando publicar um projeto no GitHub, mas sempre que dou um `git push` aparece a mensagem:

```
error: src refspec source does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/project.git'
```

Já vi algumas soluções e nenhuma resolveu. Agora isso só começou a aparecer, depois que usei o GitHub pelo Windows, tem alguma coisa a ver?

Comment: Eu faço com o `git push origin master`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Díficil dizer com 100% de certeza, mas muito provavelmente o problema é que seu branch local têm um nome diferente do branch do servidor (mais precisamente um dos dois branches, o local ou o remoto, não chama-se `master`).

Para ter certeza execute o comando `git show-ref` (que lista as referências locais). Deveria aparecer uma linha:

```
<algum SHA1>    refs/heads/master
```

E, por via das dúvidas, execute também `git ls-remote` (que lista as refências remotas). Deverá aparecer uma linha com mesmo nome de referência:

```
<algum SHA1>    refs/heads/master
```

*Seria esse seu problema?*

---

**Entendendo...**

A sintaxe (mais) completa do comando `git push` é:

```
git push <nome do remoto> <nome do branch local>:refs/heads/<nome do branch remoto>
```

Quando você utiliza a sintaxe (mencionada nos comentários) `git push origin master` o git assume `master` tanto como nome do branch local quanto do nome do remoto.

É possível utilizar nomes diferentes para os dois branches, para isso utiliza-se a forma completa ou configura-se no arquivo `.git/config`.

Se por ventura é utilizado a forma simplificada sem tal configuração a mensagem de erro é exatamente a mencionada: *"src refspec  does not match any."*. Ou seja, a parte `src` (o branch local) do *refspec* (que é o nome dessa tal sintaxe completa com `:`) não casou com nenhuma outra referência (*does not match any*). Essa "outra referência" no caso é (implicitamente) uma referência do remoto (*origin* no seu exemplo).

Em outras palavras: o git tentou utilizar o mesmo nome para os branches de origem e destino mas não encontrou branches dos dois lados com o nome dado.

Answer (score 2):

Quando criamos um projeto no local e aplicamos o comando `git init`. Uma *branch* `master` é criada automaticamente.

Quando criamos um novo repositório no *github*. Não é criado automaticamente uma *branch* `master`. Por isso o comando `git push origin master` não rola. Por que não há uma *branch* `master` no remoto ainda.

Como resolver este problema? Crie o primeiro `commit` e depois aplique o `git push`. Por costume eu crio o arquivo `.gitignore` logo após o comando `git init`, conforme exemplo a seguir:

```
touch .gitignore

git add .gitignore

git commit -m "gitignore file"

git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você deve realizar um commit antes de fazer o push.

Primeiro adiciona os arquivos com o comando:

`git add .`

Depois faça o commit:

`git commit -m "primeiro commit"`

Depois o push:

`git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema e pouco tempo. O problema era que a branch estava com nome diferente.
Quando eu corrigi o nome, foi.

Poderia ser o caso aqui.

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
```

o próprio git diz o problema, se não deu match... tem 70% de chance de ser nomeação diferente entre o repositório remoto e o local.

[image: Fim do erro após renomear a branch]

Answer (score 0):

Oi, hoje tive o mesmo problema, e a solução para o meu caso foi simplesmente manter o mesmo nome do repositório criado no github, para o repositório local.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente ver se as configurações do git estão preenchidas, eu estava com o mesmo problema pra enviar os arquivos para o meu repositório

Abra seu git Bash e digite

```
git config --list
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e ver se as váriaveis **user.name=** e **user.email=** estão preenchidas

se não estiver precha com esses comandos

```
git config --global user.name 'SEU NOME'
```

e depois

```
git config --global user.email 'SEU E-MAIL'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu caso esse o erro não apareceu mai é só seguir com o upload

exemplo:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/FernandoSena/teste.git
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score -2):

Foram realizadas algumas mudanças no GitHub, talvez o seu se chame main, então o comando é:

git push origin main

Com essa solução foi resolvido o meu problema, espero que ajude alguém