# erro ao fazer git push

Tags: git, github, heroku, commit

Estou tentando upar um projeto no github mas sempre q dou git push da esse erro:

> error: src refspec master does not match any error: failed to push
>   some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/saralvanderia.git'

Comment: Você já apontou para o branch remoto com o git remote add? Coloca na pergunta os comandos que você executou até chegar no git push. Esse erro é genérico, por isso é necessário saber como você criou o repo para  descobrir a causa do problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bem vinda ao Stackoverflow. Eu creio que o seu problema seja em relação ao nome do branch `local` ser diferente do nome do branch `remoto`. Se este for o problema, o erro está sendo gerado pois você está tentando dar um `push` num branch que não existe no  seu repositório.

Verifique usando o comando `git show-ref` (lista as referências locais) e o `git ls-remote` (lista as referências remotas).
Um caso também que pode gerar este erro é o fato de você não ter feito o seu primeiro `commit` antes de realizar o `push`.

Já existe uma pergunta criada sobre esse erro com algumas outras respostas que podem lhe ajudar a solucionar o problema. Clique aqui neste link: [problema-pra-publicar-projeto-github](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21243/problema-pra-publicar-projeto-github)

Comment: opa esse outro post me ajudou. Vlw!!

Answer (score 0):

Tente `git commit -m "primeiro commit"` e então tente `git push -u origin master` novamente.
Para mais informações dê uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309).

Espero ter ajudado.